# Unable to execute Java code after compile

Tags: java, web-services

I want to create and publish simple WebService using Java.
Everything compiles.
When I run

*>java -cp . ts.TimeServerPublisher*

I am getting error

**Error: Could not find or load main class ts.TimeServerPublisher**

Any idea why it is a problem?

My code looks like following

**TimeServerPublisher**

```
package ts;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
public class TimeServerPublisher {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/ts", new TimeServerImpl());
}
}
```

**TimeServerImpl.java**

```
package ts;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ts.TimeServer")
public class TimeServerImpl implements TimeServer {
public String getTimeAsString() { return new Date().toString(); }
public long getTimeAsElapsed() { return new Date().getTime(); } 
}
```

**TimeServer.java**

```
package ts;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) 
public interface TimeServer {
@WebMethod String getTimeAsString();
@WebMethod long getTimeAsElapsed();
}
```

Comment: You should always post your stacktrace. I bet your main class is not on the classpath - it has nothing to do with web-services.

Comment: Please post also: a) java program invocation output (stacktrace?) b) compilation command

Comment: Both are provided above. There is no stack trace. Only output is one line error. There is a Main method on in first file. The -cp flag that I added was for classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are tryin to run is in the package ts.
So if you have this file tree:

```
/bin/ts/TimeServerPublisher
```

You have to run the following command

```
java -cp /bin ts/TimeServerPublisher
```

Comment: I have the same path. C:\Users\workspace\ch01>java -cp /bin ts/TimeServerPublisher
Error: Could not find or load main class ts.TimeServerPublisher

Comment: try java ts/TimeServerPublisher in the ch01/bin folder.

Comment: hey hey it worked. Thanks Sibbo. So there is no error it stays on next line as its running. I will try to see if I could run it with a Web Server now. Why wasn't it working from ts inside the folder ?

Comment: Because the file structure of a project has to be like the package structure. There is no TimeServerPublisher class but only the ts.TimeServerPublisher class. In the filesystem it looks like ts/TimeServerPublisher.